# Checkstyle: trailing spaces regexp issue

Tags: regex, checkstyle

I'm adding Checkstyle to my project, but the rule to detect whitespaces is not good enough (RegexpSingleline):

```
(?<=\S)\s+$
```

It detects trailing spaces and ignores lines with whitespaces only (it should allow indentated blank lines). It works fine most of the time, but it complains about javadoc/multiline comments using a blank line:

```
/**
 * Some text
 * 
 * More text
 */
```

The empty line between the two lines is 'asterisk-whitespace' (default Eclipse formatting), thus triggering the rule, and so far I couldn't make it ignore this special situation. How can I fix this regexp for this case?

Thanks!

Note: it does not need to be a multiline check and verify if the line is indeed part of a comment, it is fine enough as single line.

---

Summarizing the desired rules...

The regex should match lines with trailing spaces:

```
x = y;     
void function() {
```

Except when there is nothing but whitespaces on the line (a single asterisk before the last whitespace is allowed in this exception, but ONLY when the asterisk the the only non-whitespace char):

```
(only whitespaces here, all ok)
/**
 * (this text is not here, and this line is ok - this case is my uncovered situation)
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot about this question.

In the end, my final regexp was this:

```
(?<!\A[ \t]*\*?)[ \t]$
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't this regexp fail to detect a empty line with only spaces? The solution from crasp works better in these cases.

Comment: Agreed. Eclipse Luna is also failing to match a single line with only spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the original expression

```
\s+$
```

to

```
(?<!\*)\s+$|\*\s\s+$
```

The left side of the pipe looks for whitespaces at the beginning of the line, if it's beginning with  an *.
The right side of the pipe looks for double whitespaces at the end of the line.

**Edit:**

In the meantime, the Eclipse code formatter fixed the issue with the trailing spaces in empty JavaDoc lines. Hopefully, we never have to adjust the Checkstyle regexp here again ;)

Comment: If someone else also faces the problem that checkstyle complains that `The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.`, just escape the char (replace the `<` with a `&lt;`). Took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?<=\S)(?<!^\s*\*)\s+$
```

matches whitespace at the end of a line only if it's preceded by a non-whitespace character that's also not the only asterisk on the line.

That regex requires variable-length lookbehind assertions which most regex engines do not support. So if that doesn't work, you need to match the entire line:

```
^(?!\s*(?:\*\s+)?$)(.*?)\s+$
```

and replace the matches with `\1` to remove the whitespace at the end of the line.

Comment: It is a RegexpSingleline, it won't match newlines. I can use `[ \t]`, I'm just using `\s` for easier reading. But anyway, my problem with comments remain.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the problem. Better now?

Comment: This regex is more on track, but not totally. For example, it would ignore lines like ` *      ` and `x = x *     `

Comment: The first example is identical to the line (I think) you wanted to match. What exactly is the format of the line you want to ignore?

Comment: Tim, added summarized rules to question.

Comment: Those rules are met by the regex. And `x = x * ` fulfils that rule, too - there is a single asterisk before the last whitespace.

Comment: But not the "whitespaces only" part =|

Comment: Hey, come on. You just added that restriction twenty minutes ago. Constructing a regex is just like all other kinds of programming. You need to specify *exactly*  what you want because you always get what you write, not what you think...

Comment: I can't get this regex working. Checkstyle builder complains about the '<' character that is not allowed in the value attribute in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Our (older - 5.7) version of Checkstyle uses the xml file to declare rules and is rejecting the '<' in the xml value attribute (the lookbehind token) found in the enhanced rule by @crasp.  I came up with this as an alternate solution to ignore trailing whitespace in line comments, block comments, and empty lines.  Our junior developers fail to regularly use the Eclipse formatter and they're the usual suspects for the trailing whitespace.  This rule instructs Checkstyle to ignore much of that garbage:

```
^(?!(?:[ \t]*?(?:\/?\*\*?|\/\/)[\S \t]+?|[ \t]+$))[\S \t]+[ \t]+$
```