# Eclipse Checkstyle Disable "Lline has trailing spaces"

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I'm using eclipse on Win 7. I'm also using checkstyle and find that checkstyle is complaining about trailing white space in comments.

I wish to disable this check in checkstyle, not make any modifications to my environment as I wish to share the check style file with other developers in the office an ensure everyone can see the code in the same checkstyle "light" :)

I'm okay with other built in features that would solve this problem. I've tried: `Ctrl+Shift+F` and `Ctrl+Alt+C`. Neither of which auto fix the trailing space automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the way to disable it in checkstyle:

Preferences -> CheckStyle -> Regexp -> RegexpSingleLine (Disable)

Comment: There is no point gaming the system by accepting your own answer it doesn't earn you any points.

Comment: @MartinSpamer, don't know the original intentions, but SO encourages folks to post questions and answers if it will be useful on the site (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 5):

Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions.

Press **Configure** button.

On **Code Organizing** tab check **Remove trailing whitespace**.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this changes my environment though and not the check style settings. The check style settings are contained in an xml file which I can share with other developers. I found the answer to my question and will post the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to teach Checkstyle to ignore trailing whitespaces in lines that are part of comments.

In `checkstyle.xml`:

```
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="(?!\*)[^$]\s+$"/>
    <property name="minimum" value="0"/>
    <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
    <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
</module>
```

This block basically says: "Complain about lines that do not contain an asterisk `(?!\*)`, followed by non-line-endings `[^$]`, followed by one or more spaces `\s+` followed by a line-ending `$`".

Comment: For the `format` property, I found I had to use a negative lookbehind instead of a negative lookahead. I also think `[^$]` matches everything but a dollar sign, not a newline. This worked for me: `<property name="format" value="(?&lt;!^\s+\*)\s+$"/>` It's not perfect, because it will ignore trailing whitespace on any line that starts with an asterisk (regardless of whether you're inside a Javadoc comment).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141786/1429367 which is a much more correct regex